# Why did Sita had to end her life in the way she did?

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, valmiki

Sita believed that Rama was lord Himself and accepted his wish by taking the pledge, why did she took such a pledge which would eventually end her life and separate her forever from Rama while she could have easily taken some other pledge and could have lived with Rama further.

Comment: It was time for Rama and Sita to die for Vishnu and Lakshmi to go back to Vaikuntha.